# Stock Footage and Public Domain Redubs in a Demo Reel

Tags: demo, reel, demo-reel

I need to get around to making my demo reel, but I don't have a lot of stuff to put in it -- a couple low-budget video games and one short film.  Is it acceptable to put redubs of stock and public domain footage into a demo reel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't cite any sources, but I believe reusing copyrighted stuff for personal use is not illegal, as long as you don't do commercial use of it. Now, a showreel can be seen as a bunch of things you've been exercising at, and you're not advertising it... I'd say "cite your sources and get on with it!". If you hear from anybody, well, just remove your stuff but I'm sure that by this time you'll have had the time to build yourself a proper CV!

Sometimes I wish issues were dealt by something more human than computerised people!

"Computer says nooo..." - *Little Britain* :)

Comment: Maybe I was a little off topic...

Answer (score 2):

I've certainly seen my classmates do that for their reel. Someone used footage of the bustling city of San Fransisco in 1912. Another used the footage of atomic explosions out in the Nevada desert.

I've also seen sound replacement demos of the movie, Aliens, somewhere on the interwebs. Plus, I'm doing one for a F.E.A.R. 3 game trailer. So, as it was mentioned, you could probably consider movies that are not in public domain as well.